# How do i copy rows from another sheet and paste them into a sheet that has a table in it?

Tags: vba, excel, listobject

I am working on a code and all I want to do is copy data from one sheet and paste it into another sheet that has a table setup.

My code is doing exactly what I want it to do but, the table doesn't resize to include all the rows that was copied, only the first row of the copied data goes into the table. and the rest are formatted as not in the table.

[image]

This is how it looks like after I run the code

```
Sub LastRowInOneColumn()
  Dim LastRow As Longenter image description here
  Dim i As Long, j As Long

  'Find the last used row in a Column
  With Worksheets("First Page")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  End With

  'first row number where you need to paste values in Sheet1'
  With Worksheets("Report")
    j = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '+ 1
  End With

  For i = 1 To LastRow
    With Worksheets("First Page")
      'If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "X" Then
        .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Report").range("A" & j)
        j = j + 1
      'End If
    End With
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the link to how it looks like after running the code: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AmHyJPlVM3nVgelP63-u8zHPS-wPow  

This is how I want it to look like: https://1drv.ms/i/s!AmHyJPlVM3nVgelQsGfmDhO-eCtNCQ

Comment: Can you format your table to cover the entire depth of the sheet rather than just the top row before bringing over the data

Comment: I really appreciate you guys' help. It is working now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, inserting below the end of the table will make it grow automatically, but not when pasting a range that exceeds the number of columns in the table. There are two ways to deal with this:

1- limit the copied range to the number of columns in the table; i.e.

```
.Rows(i).Resize(,4).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Report").range("A" & j)
'       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

2- Explicitly resizing the table, using the method `ListObject.Resize`; i.e.

```
With Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
  .Resize .Range.Resize(.Range.Rows.count + 1)
End With
```